# Partial Refresh Type Ahead etc No component found with ID $$ajaxid

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Since upgrading to Notes/Domino 10 I have major issues of the type..
 No component found with ID $$ajaxid=@none to handle the partial page update. [Using partial update configuration: xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=true] along with a whole host of similar problems.

I am running V10 Notes Domino, and the ODA10. The problem occurs in browsers for all users but it doesn't seem to affect those using XPiNC who haven't upgraded to Notes10. I have tried installing the latest Extension Lib on both the server and the users affected but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an unfortunate bug in Domino 10 that is fixed in the upcoming Domino 10.0.1.

See this tweet from HCL: https://twitter.com/HCL_CollabDev/status/1055467056928296961

--

**Update February, 2019:** Error handling for partial refreshes have changed in Domino 10. Add the following to xsp.properties to revert to the Domino 9 way of handling partial refresh errors:

```
xsp.error.disable.detection.set01=true
```

Source: http://linqed.eu/2019/02/07/xpages-partial-refresh-issue-in-domino-10-0-1/

Comment: Excellent, - well not excellent but you know what I mean. Many thanks Per.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, opened a PMR and asked for a HOTFIX - the North American Notes Domino development promised to do it´s best to provide a hotfix. I told them that we can´t wait until 10.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem still exists in 10.0.1. With xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=true (= evaluate entire page on refresh) and any eventhandler that is set to only update but not refresh still produces this isssue.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg have you reported the issue to IBM/HCL?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten no I did not (yet). But the 'fix/workaround' as mentioned in the tweet does work (xsp.error.disable.detection.set01=true) but I'm not sure what this exactly does. I don't like not knowing what I'm disabling exactly.

Answer (score 0):

We found a simple problem about this issue.
The default value of project XPages `Properties->Persistence->Evaluate` the entire page on partial refresh is supposed to be false, but considered as true in fact. So be careful the option is correctly set in the Source.

```
xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=false
```

Comment: I found that I already have this set, and yest still got the error in the OP. xsp.error.disable.detection.set01=true fixed it but as others said it's a bit woolly as to what this actually does.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution and that is to just disable the single error while I don't like this option, I have not found another work around at this point in time:

```
xsp.error.disable.0376=true
```

I tried using this but I do know what it actually does and there is no information about what it actually does, as if it disables a lot of error handling then I do not want to use it.

```
xsp.error.disable.detection.set01=true
```

I can see that it's said to have been fixed, but it's still not for me as I am running 10.0.1FP1